# Validity of a steady state solution of reaction-diffusion equation

Tags: simulations, biophysics, diffusion

I am performing a simulation involving growth of bacteria. This is an agent-based simulation where the solutes (glucose, oxygen etc.) are represented as a concentration field discretised over space, and the bacteria are discrete objects in a continuous space (spherical blobs with a size, mass and position).

The concentration fields diffuse throughout space, and the bacteria provide the *reaction* by taking up (or releasing) these solutes. The rate of uptake at any position in space is proportional to the amount of biomass at that position. Hence this becomes a **reaction-diffusion** problem.

The simulation is time discretised such that in one time step:

- concentration fields are solved to steady state by numerical integration of a reaction-diffusion equation for the current amount of biomass
- bacteria grow (biomass in the system changes) with respect to the updated concentration fields

I want to know, how valid is this approximation? I have always justified it that diffusion happens on a much smaller timescale than growth of the bacteria. Is it worth creating a transient solver where the reaction-diffusion equation is solved over a finite length of time and the bugs are grown for the same amount of time in a leapfrog-like scheme?

Comment: Is mass conserved? Surely if the bacteria eats a mass $m$ worth of food, then its mass should increase by the same amount (assuming there are no outlets in the bacteria). This is to say that the way I understand the issue, you in fact have to solve for both phenomena during the same time step.

Comment: @alarge No, mass is not conserved. Stochiometric coefficients are used to calculate relative yield of biomass as a function of food/O2/whatever. As I understand it, this is justified by saying we are only concerned with the reactions that affect the visible concentrations of food and biomass, and the rest of the mass is used in other reactions we are not concerned with. But yes, we have to solve for both phenomena in the same time step regardless.